# java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10034 for policy #3

Tags: java, android

I create a lock screen widget app recently. It always has the exception:

```
（ java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10034 for policy #3）
```

I try many methods and can not eliminate the exception. I open the activity to realize the purpose of the lock screen when the condition was founded.

```
public class tempActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "tempActivity"; 
    private DevicePolicyManager policyManager;
    private ComponentName componentName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);
        Log.e(TAG, "Activity created~");
        policyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        componentName = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
        mylock();
    }

    private void mylock() {
        boolean active = policyManager.isAdminActive(componentName);
        if (!active) { // Without permission
            Log.e(TAG, "No authority~");
            activeManage(); // To get access
            policyManager.lockNow(); // And lock screen
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Has authority");
            policyManager.lockNow(); // lock screen directly
        }
        this.finish();
    }

    private void activeManage() {
        Log.e(TAG, "activeManage");
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "developers：liushuaikobe");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ,, can u add entire stack trace here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is when the device admin is not active, your call to prompt it (ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN) only ensures that the user is shown the activation intent. If he or she chooses not to activate (and which is quite likely) the lock command in the next line will fail and give the error you are encountering now.
So, basically you can only prompt the users to activate the device admin, not force them.
Delete the lockNow call in the if not active block to avoid the error.
Hope this helps.
-SB

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

Comment: interesting suggestion. will try it. can you explain why this helps solve the problem?

Comment: This did not help, the SecurityException is still thrown.